# Where can I ask a question about how to use a uniquely designed font in a game?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Before I posted a question regarding **fonts** and **GIMP** in what I thought was a general area (*also don't worry I'm not whining about admin*) but my question was deleted after the admin said I needed to go here and put my question in the [appropriate place](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Now that's all cool, I click through and have a look, but this is where the problem comes in. My question seems out of place for all of these categories and I don't want to upset anymore admin, nor do I know how to message the same admin member directly and ask where it should be categorized.

So I'm really stuck, as this is something for my job (*I'm self employed*) and this is currently a major issue that needs to be sorted ASAP.
I'll post a copy of what my question was, in case anyone can help me out:

> I'm working on an indie game and as such, I've made a unique font for
>   that game but this is where the problem comes in:
>
> I don't know how to turn this into a font file that will keep all the
>   colour and textures in it and the way I'm creating words and sentences
>   with this font for my game is incredibly time consuming.
>
> I'm using GIMP and I'm essentially copying a letter, dragging where I
>   want it, to create a word or sentence, then export it as an image but
>   it's taking FOREVER to do a simple sentence and this game is very
>   dialogue heavy.
>
> Below is the logo from my game and you can see the colour and texture
>   that I want to keep:
>
> [image: The Chronicles of Drelixxe: HARPAENARN™ is a trademarked property]
>
> Does anyone know a faster way of doing this?

Now, I was thinking of putting this in Game Development, however this doesn't use a game engine (*Unity, Unreal Engine 4, Cry Engine, etc*) or blender, so it could be out of place there. I don't know if this would classify as arts & crafts either, or any coding (as some people write python scripts for GIMP) so I'm seriously stuck here and it's impacting my job too, with how time-consuming this is.

Comment: hmm- tricky one.. I'd guess if you stick to the really timeconsuming manual approach, [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) would be a reasonable fit, but I would really work with vectorized letters as a font-set here rather than copy & pasting letters to form a sentence..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) has quite a few questions about [font design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-design). This includes how to perform certain operations in computer programs used in font design. Your question might be a bit broad (*Does anyone know a faster way of doing this?*) but perhaps you can get some inspiration from the questions there, or at least an idea of the tools being used. Try them out, see if you manage to solve the problem on your own and if not, post a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it and when I was looking at sections, I wasn't able to see this before, so seriously thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I was thinking of putting this in Game Development, however this
>   doesn't use a game engine

You do not need to be using a game engine to post there. Take a look at the FAQ [what topics can be asked here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? It never mentions any game engines.

I think your question is well-suited there, but I don't know for sure. My suggestion is to post it there and find out.

Comment: I'd definitely pick Game Development here too. They can cover they appropriate angles.